Fetch Docusaurus Pages from Database
Is it possible to fetch pages from database in docusaurus? I want to implement built-in editor in Docusaurus that works without committing on github and for that, we would need database. I don't want to make a full app with frontend, backend and db, just connect docusaurus with database so that if user creates a new page from production website or edit existing one, it is saved in db and shown immediately on the website. I am not sure how to implement this would like some help
